# Directory "/proc/sys/net/bridge" missing

Tags: network-bridge, proc

I upgraded my Trusty to Linux 3.19 and the directory `/proc/sys/net/bridge` disappeared.

What's going on?

My bridge exist, I can see it through `brctl show`, but where is the directory under `/proc`? If I return to Linux 3.13, the `/proc/sys/net/bridge` appears again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to manually `modprobe br_netfilter` to get this directory.

The following kernel commit separated this out :

```
commit 34666d467cbf1e2e3c7bb15a63eccfb582cdd71f
Author: Pablo Neira Ayuso <pablo@netfilter.org>
Date:   Thu Sep 18 11:29:03 2014 +0200

    netfilter: bridge: move br_netfilter out of the core

$ git describe 34666d467cbf1e2e3c7bb15a63eccfb582cdd71f
v3.17-rc4-777-g34666d4
```

This is why 3.19 is different than 3.16.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!   :-D